# How to open Theme editor in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

My studio version is 1.3RC3,
and I cannot find Theme Editor in MainMenu/Tool/Android.

which should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I dont think they shipped it yet.

Comment: Written an article about [Android studio theme editor](http://onetouchcode.com/2016/09/27/android-studio-theme-editor/), hopefully this will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stable version of this is available in android studio 1.4 preview.
You can find it [here](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio14preview2available)

Answer (score 6):

You can find the theme editor in Android Studio - **Tools>Android>Theme Editor**.

The theme editor has been added in Android Studio 1.4 preview 1. Not all features of the theme editor are available now, more updates for customizing your own theme using theme editor will come up in the newer versions of studio.

Answer (score 1):

you could even open it using the android-studio search everywhere feature.
Press "Shift" twice and type "theme ", it will show you the theme editor in the options.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Not anymore :\ AS 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

It's no longer supported in newer android studio versions
we have to work from theme and style xml files