# Wrong background color in some android devices

Tags: java, android, xml, android-build-flavors

I'm developing an android application. I've defined a color in my resource as this:

```
  <color name="toolbar_color">#ffcb00</color>
```

I've set this color as background in one of layouts such as 'Relative layout' and this color is shown correctly in most of android devices. BUT in samsung model S6310 android 4.2.1, I have a trouble. My color is not shown and instead of showing this color, android device shows transparent color.
I've searched about this problem and the solution is using java code to set color for my layout. but I have many flavor builds and I don't want to change my java code.

Now I have 2 questions:

1- Why is this happening?

2- What's solution for this poblem?

Comment: Did you have Density based resources ? If yes, create resource file for each density. Take a look: [read more](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well to answer your question in simple terms

**Why?**

Well, this is simply the work of the Android Support Library. Android Support Library, now that it is backward compatible it should handle that. It should make the Application read those resources properly. But sometimes it doesn't. That mainly causes this.
You can read more about how to set resources if something like that happens [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility).

**Work-arounds**
Well there are many workarounds to this,

1. Set the resource colour directly in the XML instead of referencing to a resource.
2. Also you can set the resource colour or the resource using `JAVA Code`.
3. It also states that adding

   ```
   android {
       ...
       defaultConfig {
           ...
           vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
       }
       ...
     }
   ```

to the build.gradle solves the problem. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678947/how-to-properly-use-backwards-compatible-vector-drawable-with-android-support-li).

Anyway, better do it programatically.

Comment: thanks for your answer. First and third answer doesn't work and I don't want to use second answer.

Comment: @HamidrezaShokouhi No Problem. I'll look around for more solutions. But, First Solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Studio Theme Editor and try changing background color. You can get more info on Theme editor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622140/how-to-open-theme-editor-in-android-studio) and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/theme-editor.html).

Answer (score 0):

if its on android version you should check the version and set the color there

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLYBEAN) {
// Your required color
} else {

}
```

Hope this helps if its the problem with the android version.